# ComplexTypes using KSOAP

Tags: android, ksoap

I'm trying to use a webservice, where I need to work with ComplexTypes.

This is the output from the Service:

```
<req i:type="d:String"></req><File i:type="c:base64">MS4wMDE6MTYxHTEuMDAyOjAwHTEuMDAzOjEfMx4yHzAeNB8xHjQfMh0xLjAw
```

As you can see there is a `<req>` node and a `<File>` node. The req-node ends before the File-node starts. This is not what I try to accomplish, the File-Node should be inside the req-node. I'm using KSoap, and this is what I've tried:

```
SoapObject tempObject = soapObject.addProperty("req", "");
        SoapObject tempObject1 = soapObject.addProperty("File", File);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

How can I add some data to a complex type in KSOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ksoap a while ago and I added complex objects to my request with the following code:

```
public static PropertyInfo createPropertyInfo(String name, Object value, Object type) {
    PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi1.setName(name);
    pi1.setValue(value);
    pi1.setType(type);
    return pi1;
}
```

And this method is called like this:

```
request.addProperty(createPropertyInfo("complexType", objectOfComplexType, objectOfComplexType.getClass()));
```